# How to calculate Factorial For ExtraLarge Number in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
// Sample Input 
// 25
// Sample OutPut
// 15511210043330985984000000
// Code
const factorial = (n)=>{
let result = 1;
for(let i = 25; i> 0;i--){
    result = result * i;
}
    return result;
}
console.log(factorial(25)); // You will get 1.5511210043330984e+25
```

But We need Exact solution So for that check the Answer Shared.

Comment: Looks like you asked and answered your own question immediately.  Are you looking for anything more?  You can mark your own answer as the accepted answer, if you wish.

Comment: @Wyck One can mark their own answer accepted only 2 days after posting it, so the OP can't do so right now. However, the question still stands: are you looking for other answers or just wanted to share your knowledge?

Comment: Others can answer, This was my Only thought, I wanted to know the Others Approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Sample Input 
// 25
// Sample OutPut
// 15511210043330985984000000

// Code

function extraLongFactorials(n) {
  let result = 1;
  for (let i = n; i > 0; i--) {
    result = BigInt(result) * BigInt(i);
  }
  return (result.toString());
}
console.log(extraLongFactorials(25));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `n` suffix on your numbers.

```js
const factorial = n => n ? n * factorial(n - 1n) : 1n;
console.log(`25! = ${factorial(25n)}`);
```